# Relate Custom Object to County field in Leads

Tags: custom-object

I am interested in uploading and updating county-based data (population, median income, etc) in lead records via bulk look up.

I believe the most efficient and reusable method is to create a custom object, *counties*, and simply look up the county field in leads and then, using the county name in the *counties* object, upload the desired data.

My Blocker:  I can't seem to lookup and return the text field 'county' to my custom object *counties*.  What should my next step be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created lookup field (to Counties) in lead object. If so you can refer the count based data simply hovering over the lookup or bring to lead object by simple formula fields in Lead object. Is this helps?